# How to compute RSI on lower timeframe than the current timeframe?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to plot the RSI for the lowertime frame compare to the timeframe that I am currently on. I then want to plot the current timeframe rsi and lower timeframe rsi in plots together.
For the current rsi I have

```
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
plot(rsi)
```

For lower timeframe rsi I have

```
arr_rsi = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "60", ta.rsi(close, 14))
```

the issue is that `arr_rsi` is an array for each candle, lets say I compute the average of `arr_rsi` each time. How I can plot it using `plot` so it be on the same page with `plot(rsi)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `array.avg()` function for that.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
plot(rsi, color=color.green)

arr_rsi = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "1", ta.rsi(close, 14))
arr_rsi_avg = array.avg(arr_rsi)

plot(arr_rsi_avg, color=color.red)
```

[image]